# How do I diff two tables in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to compare two different tables in HBase so that I can automate the validation of some ETL processes that we use to move data in HBase. What's the best way to compare two tables in HBase?

My use case is below:

What I am trying to do is create one table that will be my expected output. This table will contain all of the data that I am expecting to be created via executing the teams code against an input file. I will then take the diff between the actual output table and the expected output table to verify the integrity of the component under test.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by comparing tables? I don't see a real reason to duplicate data into two tables? Do you want to see like a diff or are you looking for something use case specific? May be elaborating on your use case would help understand the problem a bit more.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get a diff. I added my scenario to my original question. I'm a QA Engineer for a team that does a lot of work with HBase and I am trying to automate my testing process and I am having difficulty finding diff tools for HBase.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot get just a diff of two tables in HBase. Unless you write your own custom diff type code. However, if the keys follow a particular pattern, you could do scans for the new keys which get added in during ETLs or you could ask the developers to put some new meta data in to index the latest additional keys. Then you could do a scan on that metadata and see what's different. I wish there was a better solution than that. But apart from writing a custom utility, I can't think of many ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of anything out of the box but you can write a multi-table map/reduce.

The mappers will just emit keys from each table (with a value being all the hbase key values plus a table name)
The reducer can make sure it has 2 records of each key and compare the key-values. When there's only one key it can see which table is out of sync

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a little old, but how large are the tables?  If they will both fit into memory you could load them into Pig using HBaseStorage, then use Pig's built in [DIFF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#diff) function to compare the resulting bags.

This will work even with large tables that don't fit into memory, according to the docs, but it will be extremely slow.

Comment: That could work. It needed to work with tables that do not fit into memory. I was able to get it to work using a Multi-Table Map Reduce Job using the HBase and HADOOP Apis in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset1 = LOAD '/path/to/dataset1' USING PigStorage('<your delimiter>') AS (a:chararray, b:chararray, c:chararray, d:chararray);
dataset2 = LOAD '/path/to/dataset2' USING PigStorage('<your delimiter>') AS (a:chararray, b:chararray, c:chararray, d:chararray);

dataset3 = COGROUP dataset1 BY (a, b,c, d), dataset2 BY (a, b, c, d);

dataset4 = FOREACH dataset3 GENERATE DIFF(dataset1,dataset2);
```